# The Fibonacci sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F_{2^n}}$ generalized

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, fibonacci-numbers

The evaluation,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F_{2^n}}=\frac{7-\sqrt{5}}{2}=\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2$$

was recently asked in a post by Chris [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157479).

I like generalizations, and it turns out this is not a unique feature of the Fibonacci numbers. If we use the [Pell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number) $P_m = 1,2,5,12,29,70,\dots$ then the sum is also an *algebraic number* of deg 2. In general, it seems for *any positive rational b*, then,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+4}}\left( \left(\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4}}{2}\right)^{2^n}-\left(\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4}}{2}\right)^{2^n}\right)}=1+\frac{2}{b}+\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4}}{2}$$

where Fibonacci numbers are just the case *b* = 1, the Pell numbers *b* = 2, and so on. (For negative rational *b*, then one just uses the positive case of $\pm\sqrt{b^2+4}$.)

Anyone knows how to prove/disprove the conjectured evaluation?

Comment: The induction approach mentioned in the linked post ought to work; the key point is that you can use the index-doubling formula of the associated sequence - which comes from the matrix representation of the sequence's shift operator - to explicitly express the partial sums.

Comment: (also, is there a typo in your second formula?  You use the expressions $\frac{1}{2}(b^2\pm\sqrt{b^2+4})$ where I assume you mean $\frac{1}{2}(b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4})$...)

Comment: Oops,you are right. I've corrected the typo.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your conjecture is indeed right. Before proving your conjecture, let us obtain an intermediate result first. Let us prove the following claim first.

---

**CLAIM**:

If we have a sequence given by the recurrence,
$$a_{n+2} = ba_{n+1} + a_n,$$ with $a_0 =0 $ and $a_1 = 1$, we then have
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{N} \dfrac1{a_{2^k}} = 1 + \dfrac2b - \dfrac{a_{2^N-1}}{a_{2^N}}}}$$

---

**Proof**:
Let us write out a few terms of this sequence, we get
$$a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1, a_2 = b, a_3 = b^2 + 1, a_4 = b^3 + 2b, \cdots$$
The proof is by induction on $N$. For $N=1$, we have the left hand side to be $$\dfrac1{a_1} + \dfrac1{a_2} = 1 + \dfrac1b$$ while the right hand side is $$1 + \dfrac2b - \dfrac{a_1}{a_2} = 1 + \dfrac2b - \dfrac1{b} = 1 + \dfrac1b$$
For $N=2$, we have the left hand side to be $$\dfrac1{a_1} + \dfrac1{a_2} + \dfrac1{a_4} = 1 + \dfrac1b + \dfrac1{b^3 + 2b}$$ while the right hand side is $$1 + \dfrac2b - \dfrac{a_3}{a_4} = 1 + \dfrac2b - \dfrac{b^2+1}{b^3+2b} = 1 + \dfrac1b + \dfrac1b - \dfrac{b^2+1}{b^3+2b} = 1 + \dfrac1b + \dfrac1{b^3+2b}$$ Hence, it holds for $N=1$ and $N=2$. Now lets go ahead with induction now. Assume the result is true for $N=m$ i.e. we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m} \dfrac1{a_{2^k}} = 1 + \dfrac2b - \dfrac{a_{2^m-1}}{a_{2^m}}$$
Now $$\sum_{k=0}^{m+1} \dfrac1{a_{2^k}} = 1 + \dfrac2b - \dfrac{a_{2^m-1}}{a_{2^m}} + \dfrac1{a_{2^{m+1}}}$$ Hence, we want to show that
$$ - \dfrac{a_{2^m-1}}{a_{2^m}} + \dfrac1{a_{2^{m+1}}} = -\dfrac{a_{2^{m+1}-1}}{a_{2^{m+1}}}$$
i.e.
$$\dfrac1{a_{2^{m+1}}} + \dfrac{a_{2^{m+1}-1}}{a_{2^{m+1}}} =  \dfrac{a_{2^m-1}}{a_{2^m}}$$
i.e.
$$a_{2^m}(1+a_{2^{m+1}-1}) = a_{2^m-1} a_{2^{m+1}} \,\,\,\, (\star)$$
which can be verified using the recurrence. In fact $(\dagger)$, a slightly more general version of $(\star)$, which is easier to check is true.
$$a_{2k}(1+a_{4k-1}) = a_{2k-1} a_{4k} \,\,\,\, (\dagger)$$ i.e.
$$a_{2k-1} a_{4k} - a_{2k} a_{4k-1} = a_{2k} \,\,\,\, (\dagger)$$
Hence, we get that
$$\boxed{\color{red}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{N} \dfrac1{a_{2^k}} = 1 + \dfrac2b - \dfrac{a_{2^N-1}}{a_{2^N}}}}$$

---

Now letting $N \to \infty$, we see that your conjecture is indeed right. This is so since
from the recurrence we get that
$$\dfrac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}} = b + \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$$
If we have $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = L$, then we get that
$$\dfrac1L = b + L$$ and since $L>0$, we have $L = \dfrac{\sqrt{b^2+4}-b}2$. Hence,
$$\boxed{\color{red}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{a_{2^k}} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{N} \dfrac1{a_{2^k}} = 1 + \dfrac2b - \lim_{N \to \infty} \dfrac{a_{2^N-1}}{a_{2^N}} = 1 + \dfrac2b - L = 1 + \dfrac2b + \dfrac{b}2 -\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2+4}}2}}$$

---

**EDIT**

After some googling, I found out that a similar result is true for a more general class of recurrences of the form $$a_{n+1} = P a_n + Q a_{n-1}$$ [See this article for more details.](http://www.mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/reciprocalGeomProgr.pdf)

Also, try googling [Millin series](http://goo.gl/PthLP) for more details.

Comment: +1 for going through the slog of the math and especially for the information about further generalizations - great stuff!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes. The trick was to get the right claim for finite $N$ i.e. to get $$\color{blue}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{N} \dfrac1{a_{2^k}} = 1 + \dfrac2b - \dfrac{a_{2^N-1}}{a_{2^N}}}.$$ Once we had it, the rest is just plain simple induction and then to let $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks, Marvis! (I am on vacation, so didn't see your answer till now.)

Comment: And also for the links. They were most helpful.