# How find this Fibonacci sequence sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2^k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

let sequence $\{F_{n}\}$ such $$F_{1}=1,F_{2}=1,F_{m+1}=F_{m}+F_{m-1},m\ge 2$$

Find this value

> $$I=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{F_{2^k}}$$

My try: I know this

> $$F_{n}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)^n-\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)^n\right)$$

so

> $$\dfrac{1}{F_{2^k}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)^{2^k}-\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)^{2^k}}$$
>   so
>   we only find this sum
>   $$I=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)^{2^k}-\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)^{2^k}}$$

But I can't.Thank you

Comment: There is a generalization which has this as a special case. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157820

Comment: @Tito: Oh, I feel so deflated for my proof now. I was so proud. I feel worse so, because I not only upvoted your question - I *favorited* it too. I suppose I should have been suspect when I came up with my answer so relatively quickly.

Comment: @mixedmath: Sorry. At least you knew how to prove it. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

let
$$a=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Longrightarrow \dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}=a^{-1}$$
so
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{a^{2^n}-a^{-2^n}}$$
so let $$a^{2^n}=x$$
then
$$\dfrac{1}{a^{2^n}-a^{-2^n}}=\dfrac{x}{x^2-1}=\dfrac{1}{x-1}-\dfrac{1}{x^2-1}=\dfrac{1}{a^{2^n}-1}-\dfrac{1}{a^{2^{n+1}}-1}$$
so
\begin{align*}I&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{a^{2^n}-a^{-2^n}}=\sqrt{5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{a^{2^n}-1}-\dfrac{1}{a^{2^{n+1}}-1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{a-1}-\dfrac{1}{a^{2^{n+1}}-1}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{a-1}\\
&=\dfrac{7-\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Nicely explained. (+1)

Comment: This is wrong. You need to separate the $n=0$ case.

Answer (score 12):

In fact, this is summable. This surprises me, because of results like those in [this question at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51426/reciprocals-of-fibonacci-numbers), which in short discusses how we don't know if the sum of the reciprocals of all the Fibonacci numbers is transcendental, and other related unknown results.

This question boils down to the following:

> **Claim**: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{F_1} + \frac{1}{F_2} + \frac{1}{F_4} + \ldots + \frac{1}{F_{2^n}} = 3 - \frac{F_{2^n-1}}{F_{2^n}}$ for $n \geq 2$.

*Proof*: Induct, and use $F_{n}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)^n-\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)^n\right)$ as you mentioned. $\diamondsuit$

Then take the limit as $n \to \infty$ to get that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{F_{2^k}} = \frac{7-\sqrt 5}{2}.$$