# Evaluate $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

We are given an  **infinite nested radical** as follows

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots}}},$$

which can be proven that it is convergent, namely, is equal to a real constant.

For this purpose, we consider applying the **monotone convergence principle**. Since its monotone property is obvious, what we need is to show it is bounded above.

First, we claim

> $${\frac{n}{2^{2^{n-1}}}\leq 1(\forall n)}$$

$Proof~~~~$ It's easy to show $2^{n-1}\geq n.$ For $n=1,2$, it holds trivially. For $n \geq 3$, by Newton's binominal theorem, we have $$2^n=(1+1)^n=\binom n0+\binom n1+\cdots+\binom n{n-1}+\binom nn\geq 1+n+n+1\geq 2n.$$ Thus $2^{n-1}\geq n$. Furthur, $2^{2^{n-1}}\geq 2^n \geq 2^{n-1}\geq n,$ which implies ${\dfrac{n}{2^{2^{n-1}}}\leq 1(\forall n)}$.

Next, we claim

> $${ \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}<\infty}.$$

This is a well-known result. In fact, substituting $1$ among here for any $a>0$, it's also true. For the recursion $x_1=\sqrt{a},x_n=\sqrt{a+x_{n-1}}(n\geq2)$, we can show that $a_n\leq a$, just by mathematical induction.

Now, go back to the present problem. Notice that

\begin{align*} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}&=\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac1 {2}+\sqrt{\frac2{2^2}+\sqrt{\frac3{2^4}+\cdots}}}\\ &\leq\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}\\ &<\infty, \end{align*}

which is desired.

But, my question is that, **can we evaluate it?** In another word, **can the limit be expressed as an elementary closed form?**

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/a/201219: “No closed form of this constant is known.” – See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html.